# Getting error when a component is passed in G transform rotate

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg

I am trying to animate a needle of speedometer based on a value.I would like to show an animation for the needle in which the number which i am getting is animated using a Counter component.
But when i use the component in transform i am getting the error as follows:

```
Expected [ \t\r\n], [+-], [0-9], or fractionalConstant but "[" found.
```

```
<G transform={rotate(${<Counter end={needleAngle} />} ${opts.cX} ${opts.cY})}>{needleElm}</G>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using react-native-svg node-module for this transformation then you can try this:

```js
<G
   rotation={`${<Counter end={needleAngle} />}`}
   origin={`${opts.cX} ${opts.cY}`}
>
{needleElm}
</G>
```

Comment: Do we need transform

Comment: If your animation component is doing everything then don't need of using transform.

Comment: is it possible to rotate starting from 0 to the given value

Comment: It depends on which position you are keeping your object initially